# Horizontal table view in ios 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, storyboard, xcode5, horizontalscrollview

I would like to implement a Horizontal table view in my application using xcode 5, and ios7. All references that I found were for xcode 4 and ios less than 7, and also I am using storyboards, please can somebody send me references that can help.
Thank you,
[image]

Comment: Depending on the effect you want to achieve it might be easier to use a `UICollectionView` with a horizontal flow layout.

Comment: Did you try? What is the difference? What didn't work?

Comment: yes I have tried, but it didn't work, and what I found is with xib and I want it for storybord

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import some third-party library to achieve your goal.

I recommend my framework [BWHorizontalTableView](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWHorizontalTableView), it's a high-efficiency and well-documented framework with same usage and interface as UITableView.

Just provide the `dataSource` and `delegate` like what you do when using UITableView.

```
BWHorizontalTableView *tableView = [[BWHorizontalTableView alloc] init];
tableView.frame = rect;
tableView.dataSource = your-data-source;
tableView.delegate = your-delegate;
```

Hope this would help you out.